# USB drive is rejected

Tags: usb

I stuck a USB Drive into my raspberry pi, both of which, obviously, have files on them. The pi violently told me that permission was denied, and I could not view the files on the USB Drive. Is there a command or setting I need to use or change?

**EDIT:**

When I

```
ls -la /media/usb
```

It says that /media/usb does not exist.

Comment: How is the drive formatted? What distro are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Raspian distro. The drive might be NTFS format, so I guess that could be the problem, but I thought Linux read NTFS format.

Comment: Can you read these in a different computer? If so mac or pc? and what does it show as the drive format?

Comment: I can read them on my PC. The USB is FAT32

Comment: Pis are very gentle ;-) and never violent. What was the exact error message? What does `sudo fdisk -l` show?

Comment: Let me check that real quick, and I'll get back to you. And yes, it was not violent, I was exaggerating. :)

Comment: Okay, the error message is "Not Authorized", and fdisk -l shows the USB drive, I'm pretty sure. The USB is 4 GB and it said it had 4051 MB, so that's nearly 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out! :D

This is what I did in shell:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I saw some devices listed, and identified the USB as the one I wanted because of the amount of space that it had. It was labeled as /dev/sda

I looked in the `/dev` folder and saw two files next to each other: `sda` and `sda1`

After failing to mount `/dev/sda` to `/mnt` because of it not being a block device, I mounted `/dev/sda1` and it worked!

I don't know why this is a problem, but it is for me.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/fff` (where /media/fff is a directory you have created) is the correct answer. In the `LXDE` GUI this would be mounted automatically. You can configure `/etc/fstab' to mount automatically.